# maven is wrongly using the version number I provided, why

Tags: maven, dependencies

I introduced `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.14.0`  in pom.xml, but I ended up using the version number `7.12.1` provided in springboot, why?

I need the 7.14.0 version

[End-use version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL4yV.png)

[spring-boot-dependencies[pom.xml]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q2IZ.png)

[easy-es-parent[pom.xml]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vaic.png) |
[easy-es-common[pom.xml]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLXrr.png)

This is my complete pom.xml file
https://gist.github.com/2720851545/b75a50bd0119590f928d1e70a99ea03f

Answer (score 0):

In Maven, any transitive dependency-version might be used, you could try to explicitly state in the POM which version for that given dependency you want to have.
With maven dependency-plugin, it should be transparent which dependency-version will be effective:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: But why is the version number 7.12.1, and not 7.14.0?

Comment: This is just up to Maven, and there is no predictable choice made. You might have to specify the version in the POM accordingly or exclude undesired transitive 7.12.1..